docker compose with Galera Cluster
I am setting a Galera Cluster using docker compose on my CentOS AlmaLinux 8.
Here is the firts attempt:
docker-compose.yml :
services:
  sv-isoluce-galeradb-1:
    build:
      context: ./buildimg/galeradb
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: img-isoluce-galeradb
    container_name: ct-isoluce-galeradb-1
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      CLUSTER_NAME: ${CLUSTER_NAME}
      NODE_NAME: "isoluce-galera-node1"
      CLUSTER_JOIN: "isoluce-galera-node2,isoluce-galera-node3"
      WSREP_ON: "ON"
      WSREP_SST_METHOD: "mariabackup"
      WSREP_CLUSTER_ADDRESS: "gcomm://isoluce-galera-node2,isoluce-galera-node3"
    volumes:
      - vl-isoluce-ct-galeradb-1:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./ctconfig/galeradb-1.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    ports:
      - "3301:3306"
    networks:
      nw_isoluce_galeradb_cluster_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.16.11
volumes:
  vl-isoluce-ct-galeradb-1:
    name: vl-isoluce-ct-galeradb-1
  vl-isoluce-ct-galeradb-2:
    name: vl-isoluce-ct-galeradb-2
  vl-isoluce-ct-galeradb-3:
    name: vl-isoluce-ct-galeradb-3

networks:
  nw_isoluce_galeradb_cluster_network:
    name: nw_isoluce_galeradb_cluster_network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.16.0/24

And the Dockerfile I use to build my own image :
FROM mariadb:10.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    iputils-ping \
    vim \
    nano \
    net-tools \
    htop \
    wget \
    curl \
    atop \
    netcat-openbsd \
    systemd \
    procps \
    locate \
    telnet \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 3306


And my galera nodes are using the same configuration file (just the number of node and IP address change):
[mysqld]
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
general_log = on
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log

performance_schema=ON
performance_schema_instrument = '%=ON'
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_current=ON
performance_schema_consumer_events_statements_history=ON

wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://isoluce-galera-node1,isoluce-galera-node2,isoluce-galera-node3
wsrep_cluster_name=isoluce-galera-cluster
wsrep_node_address=192.168.16.11
wsrep_node_name=isoluce-galera-node1
wsrep_sst_method=mariabackup
binlog_format=ROW


Build is OK. But when I create the containers, they are not active :
docker compose up -d
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                     PORTS                                   NAMES
9b8625cd50f0   img-isoluce-galeradb           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 seconds ago   Exited (1) 8 seconds ago                                           ct-isoluce-galeradb-1


The log file does not provide more information unfortunately:
docker logs ct-isoluce-galeradb-1
2024-09-23 08:24:07+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.5.26+maria~ubu2004 started.
2024-09-23 08:24:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2024-09-23 08:24:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.5.26+maria~ubu2004 started.
2024-09-23 08:24:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required

After searching a while, it seems the problem comes from the configuration file:
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

When commenting this line, the containers stay active but no synchronization of course...
This file exists :
sudo docker exec -it ct-isoluce-galeradb-1 /bin/bash
root@d0d1435917bc:/# ls -al /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jul 23 00:18 /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so -> ../libgalera_smm.so
root@d0d1435917bc:/# ls -al /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 67562104 Jul 23 00:18 /usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so

Even adding the following command to the Dockerfile to modify the rights on the file does not solve the problem:
 RUN chmod 755 /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

Any idea?
Thank you
NOTE: I know it is a symbolic link but changing it to the file does not solve the problem
NOTE: I tried with FROM mariadb:10.5 and FROM mariadb:latest
NOTE: I added the following package into my Dockerfile : galera-4 but without change...

I see you just check docker logs, do you check mysql log?
You can bind mount(volume config in compose file) a folder from host to /var/log/mysql in container, just like your /var/lib/mysql, so you can check the log generated by mysqld; If you are familiar with overlayfs, you can directly find them in /var/lib/docker/overlay/xxxx without bind mount; I think you might also check if the host folder is writable for user mysql in container, or just make them world writable/executable

ok I just added the volume to my container : docker inspect c2cefb10395f | grep log
"LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c2cefb10395f5255fe1d808c90985c88fd45143e6a13945fc9cbf0b86b0aa7c7/c2cefb10395f5255fe1d808c90985c88fd45143e6a13945fc9cbf0b86b0aa7c7-json.log",
"/home/yoong/softs/docker/3-dc-galera/ctconfig/log/mysql-1_log:/var/log/mysql/mysql.log:rw",
"Source": "/home/yoong/softs/docker/3-dc-galera/ctconfig/log/mysql-1_log",
"Destination": "/var/log/mysql/mysql.log",
nothing in the log file unfortunately...thank you for the idea

Anybody faced to the same problem? Am I the only one?

You're trying to set up a three node galera cluster but you only have a single container in your compose file. The hostnames you're using in your configuration don't match the hostnames assigned to your containers. You're never bootstrapping a new cluster as described in the documentation. You're defining some configuration in environment variables but then defining the same things in a configuration file.
